pythonnet loading mixed mode assembly
I had a problem with loading one legacy NET dll using pythonnet
It's third party dll and it built for V2.0.50727
I'm using python 3.8.9 x86 and pythonnet 3.0.3
I've create config file python.exe.config with below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
            <section name="customAppSettings" 
                    type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, 
                    System.Configuration" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <customAppSettingsGroup>
        <customAppSettings>
             <add key="Debugger" value="True"/>
        </customAppSettings>
    </customAppSettingsGroup>
    
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>

I loaded dll like so
from pythonnet import set_runtime, get_runtime_info
import clr

print(Environment.Version.ToString())
print(Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture.ToString())

clr.AddReference("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Dynamics AX/40/Client/Bin/Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll")

it prints
4.0.30319.42000
X86
and finally
mixed mode assembly is built against version v2.0.50727 of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information
There I'm stuck. I used that before from c# project, but not with python. According to many similar Q&As this should work, but maybe I'm missing something?

Finally found what's wrong. I applied config to wrong python installation. With help of setting COMPLUS_CLRLoadLogDir env var I figured out actual python.exe place, set python.exe.config and voila, all works!

